# Unable to generate regex for the string

Tags: regex

I have a string `abc-[|123|243|]-xyz-[|432|567|]` and I want to generate a regex that matches the specific string.

The regex should be tested against the following examples and with the specific result.

Exp 1: `abc-[|123|234|]-xyz-[|432|567|]` (`123` is present in `[|123|243|]`)

Result : **Match**

Exp 2: `xyz-[|123|243|]-abc-[|432|567|]` (order of `abc` and `xyz` interchanged)

Result : **No match**

Exp 3: `abc-[|243|563|]-xyz-[|432|567|]` (`243` and `432` are present)

Result : **Match**

Exp 4: `xyz-[|143|434|]-abc-[|432|999|]` (`[|148|434|]` not match of any number in  `[|123|243|]`)

Result : **No match**

I tried creating a regex but its only working in the exact case and not working in other cases.

`abc-\[\|123\||243\|\]-xyz-\[\|432\||567\|\]`

Comment: Could you please show the regex?

Comment: So, what is your regex pattern? BTW: i doubt that regex is able to get exact order (Exp. 2).

Comment: I have mentioned it at the bottom of the question but still, it's here abc-[|123||243|]-xyz-[|432||567|]

Comment: Try `^(?:abc-\[\|(?:123|243)\|[^][]*]-xyz-\[\|432\|[^][]*\|\])$`, see https://regex101.com/r/RIcCqn/1

Comment: Or,  if there can only be two numbers, `^(?:abc-\[\|(?:123|243)\|\d+\|]*]-xyz-\[\|432\|\d+\|\])$`, see https://regex101.com/r/Um2cMu/1

Comment: Yes its working but there's one problem with it. If I test it against the abc-[|123|243]-xyz-[|432|567|]  same string it's not working.

Comment: Does it mean the `|` next to closing `]` is optional? Pease describe the actual rules. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Um2cMu/3)

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake the | and closing ] are not optional and there's one more thing if i replace the order of numbers from one bracket to another it is still showing it's a match or if I add one more number to test case then it is not showing if it's a match. I'm sorry if I made any mistake , I am new to regex.

Comment: Wait, is `^(?:abc-\[\|(?:123|243)\|\d+\|\]-xyz-\[\|432\|\d+\|\])$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/Um2cMu/4)) working as expected? If not, please use the regex fiddle to explain and showcase the problem

Comment: Yes, it's working perfectly now. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^abc-\[\|(?:123|243)\|\d+\|\]-xyz-\[\|432\|\d+\|\]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Um2cMu/5).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `abc-\[\|` - `abc-[|`
- `(?:123|243)` - either `123` or `243`
- `\|` - a `|`
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\|\]-xyz-\[\|432\|` - a `|]-xyz-[|432|` text
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\|\]` - a  `|]` text
- `$` - end of string