# I am trying to make my regex work in MySQL but it's not working

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a string stored in my sql database that says

`rahul-scored-[ 99 58 21 ]-marks`

and I have REGEX for it

`^rahul-scored-\[[ \d{2}]* (?:99|58|21) [\d{2} ]*\]-marks$`

When I test it in Javascript it return true but if I check it in MySQL using

```
SELECT * 
from tablexyz 
WHERE columnabc RLIKE '^rahul-scored-\[[ \d{2}]* (?:99|58|21) [\d{2} ]*\]-marks$'
```

it does not return any row.

**Is there any way to write the exact same regex for MySQL without changing the meaning and sense of REGEX expression.**

Comment: Please explain what you want the regular expression to do.  It is using back references, which MySQL does not support.

Comment: You need to change its meaning since `[ \d{2}]*` is not doing what you thing it is.Try `'^rahul-scored-\\[( *[0-9]{2})+ *]-marks$'`, see https://regex101.com/r/53x2DD/1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64332002/unable-to-generate-regex-for-the-string?noredirect=1#comment113762084_64332002 I want to do something like this.

Comment: I want to check whether the given string contains only these three numbers or one of them.

Comment: Only MySQL version 8 handles that regexp syntax.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
REGEXP '^rahul-scored-\\[( (99|58|21))+ \\]-marks$'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IvvaTm/1).

**Details**

- `^rahul-scored-\\[` - a literal `rahul-scored-[` text at the start of string
- `( (99|58|21))+` - one or more repetitions of a space and then either `99`, `58` or `21`
- `\\]-marks$` - the  `]-marks` string at the end of string.

Points of interest:

- The regex escapes (like `\[` that matches a literal `[`) must be escaped as `\\[` because the pattern is defined using a string literal
- You cannot use *non-capturing groups* if you use MySQL versions older than 8.

Comment: It is working when I am changing \[ to \\[ and \] to \\]

Comment: @VipinGautam Like the one above?

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want:

```
WHERE columnabc RLIKE '^rahul-scored-\\[( [0-9]{2})* \\]-marks$'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f7832f84c598f24f110ce8de344ec973) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I tried but it is working for every two-digit number. I want to check exclusively whether any of these three numbers is present.